# How can I safe get a value from STL map or unordered_map?

Tags: c++, stl

How can I safe get the value by key from STL map or unordered_map?
The obvious answer is

```
const auto it = map.find(key);
if (it != std::end(map))
{ 
  myValue = get<1>(*it);
}
else
{
  // no key case ...
}
```

By this code is used so often, why does not STL contain helper methods something similar to `TryGetValue` from C# ? STL already contains a lot of helpers, e.g. `std::get<>()`, `std::make_...<>()`, `std::begin\end()` and so on.  So `std::try_get()` would follow this logic.

Something similar to:

```
namespace std
{
    template<class Key, class T, class Hash = hash<Key>, class KeyEqual = equal_to<Key>, class Allocator = allocator< pair<const Key, T>>>
    bool try_get(const unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, Allocator>& map, const Key& key, T* value)
    {
        const auto it = map.find(key);
        const bool res = it != end(map);
        if (res && value != nullptr)
        {
            *value = get<1>(*it);
        }

        return res;
    }

    template<class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>, class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T>>>
    bool try_get(const map<Key, T, Compare, Allocator>& map, const Key& key, T* value)
    {
        const auto it = map.find(key);
        const bool res = it != end(map);
        if (res && value != nullptr)
        {
            *value = get<1>(*it);
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

*Examples:*
This method would be helpful in case when you have a map of predefined values but default value is also suits you:

```
std::map<TKey, TValue> settings = /* deserialization */;

...

TValue myValue = /* default value */ ;
std::try_get(settings, key, &myValue);

// use myValue in following code, 
// it contains ether default or predefined value from settings
```

Another example, you have several caches with initialized objects and you need to use any of them that correspond key or fallback to default implementation when caches do not contain key associated object.

```cpp
std::map<TKey, TObjKeeper> generalDependecyObjects = /* initialization */;
std::map<TKey, TObjKeeper> specificDependecyObjects = /* initialization */;

TObjKeeper obj;
if (!std::try_get(generalDependecyObjects, objectId, &obj) &&
    !std::try_get(specificDependecyObjects, objectId, &obj))
{
  obj = /*fallback to default implementation*/;
}
```

Comment: you can submit a proposal.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I think it's such an obvious idea that there must be a reason why it has not been implemented yet. There may already be a way how to do this with existing STL helpers, but I don't know it.

Comment: imho it would help if you added an example use case. I dont see yet how using your `try_get` would be much simpler than the original code with `find` and then checking the iterator. You now call `try_get` and then still write the if-else to check what the returned value was

Comment: It's trivial to write your own function to do what you want, why would it need to be part of the standard library?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, ok, agree. just thought that code simplification helpers could also be part of STL like `std::make_tuple\pair` or `std::begin\end`.

Comment: the issue with "why is it not in the standard library" is that the reason why something is in the standard library is that someone wrote a proposal and put effort in it. This wasnt the case with `map::try_get`. Perhaps not yet. I do not see the benefit of having this standardized. Too many similar closely related usecases that require a different signature. I see no technical reason that it isnt in though, you already demonstratet that it can be implemented. Despite my answer, I believe this question boils down to being opinion based

Comment: on the other hand, someone might be aware of a proposal of this or similar, then we would know more about "why" or "why not"

Comment: Rather than returning a bool and assigning through a pointer, you could return `std::optional<Value>` (or a pointer, which lets you access the value itself)

Comment: @Caleth, good note, variant with `std::optional` result is much better current proposition.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `try_get` does not handle the `else`, so you would still have to write an `if-else`, not to check the iterator returned from `find` but to check the `bool` returned from `try_get`.

Moreover you need to consider that there is a conditional init-statment allowed in if statements. Hence you rather need to compare against:

```
if (auto it = map.find(key); it!=std::end(map))
{ 
  myValue = get<1>(*it);
}
else
{
  // no key case ...
}
```

And now I am not sure anymore if you can convince others that the following would be so much better:

```
DataType value;  // must be default constructible!
if (try_get(map,&value))
{ 
  myValue = get<1>(value);
}
else
{
  // no key case ...
}
```

Comment: i added examples to my question. there are many cases when default value is also valid so `else` branch is unnecessary or when you should check several maps one by one so `else` would be nightmare or you have to implement loop code.

Comment: @23W yes, there are many variations, which is a big reason why this hasn't been standardized

Comment: @Caleth, i don't understand this `big reason`. MS exactly because of this reason implemented the method [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-7.0) in .Net and it's useful.

Comment: @23W I dont know c#, but  is a big difference to have a method included from the start or to add it retroactively. Adding something to the standard is a load of work for many, you need really good reasons to get something in that already can be done with existing methods